# Eclipse Listener to detect File changes?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, listener

I am searching a listener in Eclipse, that will detect if a file is changed externally by third party software, like MKS.

I used `IResourceChangeListener` and it worked. But problem is, it also listens other changes of the file. For example, when I delete the markers, it also listens and execute the codes I wanted after listening.

Is there any Listener, which listens only if the file is changed (newly opened/refreshed) by third party software?

**Updated:**

My code:

```
public class Startup implements IStartup {

       IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
       IResourceChangeListener listener = new IResourceChangeListener() {

        public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {


               if(event.getType() == IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE && IResourceDelta.MARKERS!=0){  //Filtering listener


                System.out.println("Listener code should be implemented here");  


              }


               System.out.println("listener is working");  //This line always get executed. That means the listener is working


           }
       };



    @Override
    public void earlyStartup() {
       workspace.addResourceChangeListener(listener,IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE);

       //... some time later one ...
      // workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(listener);
    }


}
```

Comment: Eclipse doesn't normally notice changes by non-Eclipse code at all unless you have 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' set in the preferences (or you use 'Refresh')

Comment: I think, when I am deleting the markers, the file gets refreshed and therefore the listener is executing codes for every single marker deletion. If I remove 10 markers at a time, it executes my listener code for 10 times. How can I prevent it? Then, I can go with IResourceChangeListener as its serving my purpose.

Comment: `IResourceDelta` has flags telling you what has been changed check those

Comment: Thanks. I am checking it now.

Comment: I tried with all the flags of IResourceDelta. But it seems, for following 2 activities, all flag changes are same: 1) Removing all markers of existing workspace 2)File change on the file system. I am trying to get the flags, that changes are different for these 2 activities. Any idea?

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the delta for the actual file, not the workspace, project or folder. Markers should have the MARKERS flag, file content change the CONTENT flag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my question with my codes. I tried to get deltas for a file according to your suggestion, but it seems file doesn't support getDelta() method. Only resource event has delta method and resource events belongs to resource listener, which also belongs to workspace only, I cant implement a listener for a file.

Comment: A resource delta has children. Use the `accept(IResourceDeltaVisitor)` method of the delta to visit all the children.

Comment: @greg-449: Thanks. I am checking it now.

Comment: Thanks greg-449. I just implemented the listeners in my project. I followed your suggestion and IResourceDelta.CHANGED & IResourceDelta.CONTENT served my purpose.