# How eclipse understand file changes in file system?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, listener

While working on eclipse, if you change any file outside of eclipse, a dialog comes up in eclipse with message:

[image]

How eclipse detects it? I think eclipse has some kind of listeners to detect that the file has changed in file system. I need to know that listener API.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Comment: Do you have the 'Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh using native hooks or polling' option selected?

Comment: Did you not already ask it 2 hours before ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27420787/4296831

Comment: @Joachim : Not actually. Thats a different question. Here, I wanted to know, which listener Eclipse uses to trigger that dialog. Eclipse may work in different way than I intend to. It may even don't use a listener.

Comment: This also happens with word document, notepad++ and many other text document reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the class which detects changes, triggers the event etc. when file is changed in the workspace on the file system.

From [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2Frefresh%2FRefreshProvider.html):

> **RefreshProvider#createPollingMonitor()** Creates a new refresh monitor that performs
>   naive polling of the resource in the file system to detect changes.
>   The returned monitor will immediately begin monitoring the specified
>   resource root and report changes back to the workspace.

You can try configuring eclipse source to understand more in detail, can refer [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_refresh.htm) & [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_filesystem.htm) for more details.

[Implementation for win32 filesystem : *`org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.refresh.win32.Win32RefreshProvider`*]

You can also provide custom refresh monitor by extending `RefreshProvider` & configuring it as demonstrated in link; hope this helps.